# DataMapper CodeIgniter Relation One to One

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am trying to work with something like this:
(I need to split up the users table)

```
===================

table users


id | pseudo | password
id PK

===================

table users_infos

user_id | stats | etc etc
user_id FK (>users>id) 

===================

model user

$has_one = array('users_info)

model users_info

$has_one = array('user)

//
```

My issue here comes from the table `users_infos`. With no `Id` field I cannot use the save method for updating. I try to rewrite the column `user_id` to `id` but then I loose the foreign key from `DataMapper`. What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making it a one to many relationship make a `users_info_id` field on the user table and make it unique.

also change the `user_id` field on `users_info` to just id

Models should be like this:
    model user
    $has_one = array('users_info')

```
model users_info
$has_one = array('user')
```

That way it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Every table should have an 'id' column, it's required.

Ideally it's defined as auto-increment, and it shouldn't always have a meaning, the 'id' is just a way to uniquely identify the correct table row.

You need to define relations both ways, so the previous answer is not going to work.